# Searching for an RFID car key

Tags: rf, antenna, rfid

I want to locate a lost car key. It’s a 2004-vintage classic metal transponder key (not just a fob as is used in modern “pushbutton start” cars) which uses the immobilizer system (125 KHz?) to identify the RFID circuit in the key handle.

I can get to within probably 6” (15 cm) of where I suspect the key is. The area is quite large but the depth to search is fairly shallow. Manual searching has thus far failed. There is metal in the search area so a metal detector or magnet are useless.

I am thinking to output to a loop antenna the 125 KHz (maybe sweep either side of that a little) and use an audio tone (ie, 1 KHz?) and listen for changes when the key is in range. No need to communicate (challenge/response) with the key.

I’d like to use existing equipment and not build everything from scratch (ie, use a cheap sig gen rather than build the oscillator).

I have a spare key to experiment with.

A new key and programming is more than US$200 so I’m motivated to try something fun and geeky...

I’m looking for design ideas and assistance (directions only—I can build it) re. circuit details and components.

Thanks.

Comment: Time for a cost-benefit analysis. How much stuff could there possibly be within your 12" search area that it could be even remotely more efficient to try to build & debug an RFID locator instead of just digging up that area to a depth of a few inches...?

Comment: I guess you could find these keys through a wall, eh? That would be fun and geeky

Comment: where do you suspect the key to be?

Comment: This question makes little sense, an area (volume) that small could easily be searched by hand in the time it took to post this question.

Comment: Where are you looking?  In sand, mud, shallow water, crawlspace under a floor?

Comment: This isn’t an RFID communication challenge. It’s just a grid-dip-oscillator and audio detector, if my idea is sound.

Comment: The search area covers approx. 1000 linear feet of metal shelving. Access (by the clock) is limited. Material on the shelves among which the key is somewhere, cannot be moved. These are the limitations. I could just buy another key but I like the challenge.

Comment: I am not looking for people to tell me it’s not worth it. I’ve decided it is. I’m looking for someone to coach me in my efforts. Thanks.